# Find information from an array using another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have this problem where I cannot seem to find an answer specific to my problem.

```
Array1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
Array2 = ["item2", "item5"]
```

I am looking to use the information from array2 to find within array1.

An example for this to output

> Array1 has item2 and is at Array1[1]

If anyone can help me, thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't your example output mention `"item5"`? Can the same string potentially occur more than once in `Array1`? What have you tried so far? I'm thinking a simple `for` loop over `Array2` with a call to `Array1.indexOf()` would get the job done easily enough. If your question is "Please code the whole thing for me" what you really want is a JS tutorial - there are links to some on the [SO JS info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Comment: What is your question? You merely stated facts about the arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array2.forEach((e) => {
    const indexOfE = Array1.indexOf(e)
    if (indexOfE > -1) {
        console.log(`Array1 has ${e} and is at Array1[${indexOfE}]`)
    }
})
```

You can have a look at [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to help you understand this code.

**Edit**

Answering the question in the comments, if you want to check the elements in Array1 that contain elements of Array2 as substrings, then you can:

```
Array2.forEach((e) => {
    Array1.forEach((f, i) => {
        if (f.toLowerCase().includes(e)) {
            console.log(`Array1 has ${e} and is at Array1[${i}]`)
        }
    })
})
```

Check [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript) for details on finding substrings in another String.

Comment: Outstanding answers. Thank you. One question. Would it be possible to have `Array2` search more in terms of find the word specifically regardless of how it is within `Array1`? More like an includes or contains method. For example say it was " largeitem1 " and `Array2` still had "item1"

Comment: @UndefinedUsername yes, check the edit for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know Array1 contains an element from Array2 then iterate over Array2 calling indexOf for each element:

```
Array2.map((el => {
    if (Array1.indexOf(el) !== -1) {
        console.log('Array 1 contains ' + el);
    }
}));
```

Comment: `.forEach()` is a better choice than `.map()`. The result is the same, but `.map()` implies that you are, well, *mapping* something. Which you're not.

Comment: Yes you're right. I tend to opt for map out of habit - but foreach is better here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
var Array1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
var Array2 = ["item2", "item5"];
for (var i = 0; i <Array2.length; i++) {
 if (Array1.indexOf(Array2[i])>-1) {
 console.log("Array1 has "+Array2[i]+" and is at Array1["+Array1.indexOf(Array2[i]) +"]")  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Ramdajs to find intersection of two arrays as follows

```
const Array1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
const Array2 = ["item2", "item5"];

const res = R.intersection(Array1, Array2);
console.log(res);
```

[here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20Array1%20%3D%20%5B%22item1%22%2C%20%22item2%22%2C%20%22item3%22%2C%20%22item4%22%2C%20%22item5%22%5D%3B%0Aconst%20Array2%20%3D%20%5B%22item2%22%2C%20%22item5%22%5D%3B%0A%0AR.intersection%28Array1%2C%20Array2%29) is the code repel

The same could be achieved using lodash

```
const Array1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
const Array2 = ["item2", "item5"];
const res = _.intersection(Array1, Array2)
console.log(res);
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/user93/ba5gqn3e/) is the jsfiddle for lodash.

or you could use the includes method of the array to do the same

```js
const Array1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
const Array2 = ["item2", "item5"];
const res = Array1.filter(curr=>Array2.includes(curr));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: ,, you are obsessed by ramda .